# Confused about ODAC (xcopy version) installation path

Tags: oracle, odac

As I am getting this notorious error 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client' with my asp.net application, I am trying to install the same ODAC version which my team is using: ODAC 11.2.0.4.0.

So, I downloaded it and extracted to the following location:

C:\Users\user0792\Downloads\ODAC112040Xcopy_64bit

The readme file is the same as the one here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/odac-11-155128.html

In which, it says:

`install.bat all c:\oracle odac`

`Each product can be also be installed and configured individually. As an example, executing the following will install only ODP.NET 2:`

`install.bat odp.net2 c:\oracle odac`

`where "c:\oracle", for example, is your installation directory and "odac" is the Oracle Home Name that is used for the registry keys. In this example, the registry entries for this install is created under HKLM\Software\Oracle\KEY_odac. Note that ODP.NET registry entries are simply  created under HKLM\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\, and not under HKLM\Software\Oracle\KEY_. If multiple products are installed to the same destination directory, make sure that the Oracle Home Name that is specified as an argument to install.bat is the same for all those products.`

Is it suggesting that regardless of where my oracle client is installed, I can install ODAC to c:\oracle?  If it matters, my oracle client is installed at `C:\oracle\Client64\product\11.2.0\client_1`

Should I just simply follow the instruction and issue `install.bat all c:\oracle odac` to install all?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is your asp.net also 64-bit? It has to be the same as your Oracle Client. Which kind of client do you have installed in `C:\oracle\Client64\product\11.2.0\client_1`? Installing several versions of Oracle client can be very tricky, you have to shuffle around with `PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` variable. Configuration of GAC can be difficult.

Comment: If you use .NET framework 4.x you can use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll that is all-in-one library that not need of oracle client components

Comment: My asp.net application is configured to build for “Any CPU”. My dev box run 64 bit windows 10.  The client is pretty standard so I can use SQL*Plus and SqlDeveloper to connect to Oracle instances.

Comment: I don’t have that option. I have to use Oracle.DataAccess.dll because I am working on an old application.